# company-clang always No completion found

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

i have post and issue on company-mode's git site, but i cant't draw any attention there, maybe author is in some kind of busy recently. so i post here now.

when i setup the company, and want to use it.
there are always:

```
No completion found
user-error: Cannot complete at point
```

here is my init setup:

```
(require 'cc-mode)
(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(setq company-backends (delete 'company-semantic company-backends))
(define-key c-mode-map [(tab)] 'company-complete)
(define-key c++-mode-map [(tab)] 'company-complete)
(setq company-clang-executable "/usr/bin/clang-3.8")
```

and i also found, when i want to exit the emacs, i found compay-clang still running(have a active buffer, shown in process list):

```
company-clang run *clang-output* /dev/pty1 /usr/bin/clang-3.8 -fsyntax-only -Xclang -code-completion-macros -x c++ -I/cygdrive/e/lua/include -I/usr/include -Xclang -code-completion-at=-:28:5 -
```

btw, i use this setup(almost the same, such as include path) for auto-complete-clang, and it works fine.

i seems that company-clang have been running into a loop, because when i try to close the clang-output buffer, it always left a message which is "Buffer "clang-output" has a running process; kill it? (yes or no) ".
but the more important is that there is nothing in that buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use pipes instead of PTYs to receive output from Clang](https://github.com/juergenhoetzel/company-mode/commit/92b0bf73c49cca1221893fe4d2463bfede49c013)